# Scraping JavaScript var from website using Beautiful Soup in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping a website's HTML after a "GET" request. There is product1218181 parameter on the site I want to extract data from, so there is product{1218181}. I'm using Beautiful soup since it's what I usually use but I can't seem to figure out how to get a javascript variable from the html. HTML like so:

```
<script>var product1218181 = {"name":"XIAOMI Poco X3 Pro 256 GB Akıllı Telefon Bronz","id":"1218181","price":"5799.00","brand":"XIAOMI","ean":"6934177738371","dimension25":"InStock","dimension26":11.90,"dimension24":18.00,"category":"Telefon","dimension9":"Cep Telefonları","dimension10":"Android Telefonlar"};</script>
```

I would like to scrape like this:

```
name: XIAOMI Poco X3 Pro 256 GB Akıllı Telefon
id: 1218181
price: 5799.00
brand: XIAOMI
```

Update

Full code like this, I would like to scrape this website products infos

```
import requests
import re, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.mediamarkt.com.tr/tr/category/_cep-telefonlar%C4%B1-504171.html"
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

results = soup.find(id="category")

test = '<script>var product1218181 = {"name":"XIAOMI Poco X3 Pro 256 GB Akıllı Telefon Bronz","id":"1218181","price":"5799.00","brand":"XIAOMI","ean":"6934177738371","dimension25":"InStock","dimension26":11.90,"dimension24":18.00,"category":"Telefon","dimension9":"Cep Telefonları","dimension10":"Android Telefonlar"};</script>'

pattern = re.compile('.*?var product1218181 = (.*?);.*?')
match = pattern.match(test)
if match is not None:
    data = json.loads(match.groups()[0])
    for key, value in data.items():
        print(key, ":", value)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select the variable in your `requests.get().text` with regex and load the string with `json.loads()`:

```
m = re.search(r'var product.+ = ({.*})', page.text)
json.loads(m.group(1))
```

#### Example to get list of dicts:

```
import requests
import re, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.mediamarkt.com.tr/tr/category/_cep-telefonlar%C4%B1-504171.html"
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
data = [json.loads(m.group(1)) for m in re.finditer(r'var product.+ = ({.*})', page.text)]
```

#### Output

```
[{'name': 'XIAOMI Poco X3 Pro 256 GB Akıllı Telefon Bronz', 'id': '1218181', 'price': '5799.00', 'brand': 'XIAOMI', 'ean': '6934177738371', 'dimension25': 'InStock', 'dimension26': 11.9, 'dimension24': 18.0, 'category': 'Telefon', 'dimension9': 'Cep Telefonları', 'dimension10': 'Android Telefonlar'}, {'name': 'APPLE iPhone 12 64GB Akıllı Telefon Yeşil', 'id': '1212811', 'price': '14749.00', 'brand': 'APPLE', 'ean': '0194252030943', 'dimension25': 'InStock', 'dimension26': 11.9, 'dimension24': 18.0, 'category': 'Telefon', 'dimension9': 'Cep Telefonları'}, {'name': 'SAMSUNG Galaxy A22 128 GB Akıllı Telefon Beyaz', 'id': '1217491', 'price': '3499.00', 'brand': 'SAMSUNG', 'ean': '8806092288300', 'dimension25': 'InStock', 'dimension26': 11.9, 'dimension24': 18.0, 'category': 'Telefon', 'dimension9': 'Cep Telefonları', 'dimension10': 'Android Telefonlar', 'dimension11': 'Samsung Telefon'}, {'name': 'XIAOMI Redmi 9T 128 GB Akıllı Telefon Yeşil', 'id': '1216309', 'price': '3399.00', 'brand': 'XIAOMI', 'ean': '6934177746031', 'dimension25': 'OutOfStock', 'dimension26': 11.9, 'dimension24': 18.0, 'category': 'Telefon', 'dimension9': 'Cep Telefonları', 'dimension10': 'Android Telefonlar'}, {'name': 'APPLE iPhone 12 128GB Akıllı Telefon Siyah', 'id': '1212812', 'price': '15699.00', 'brand': 'APPLE', 'ean': '0194252031285', 'dimension25': 'InStock', 'dimension26': 9.99, 'dimension24': 18.0, 'category': 'Telefon', 'dimension9': 'Cep Telefonları'}, {'name': 'APPLE iPhone 11 64GB Akıllı Telefon Sarı', 'id': '1212830', 'price': '10349.00', 'brand': 'APPLE', 'ean': '0194252098264', 'dimension25': 'InStock', 'dimension26': 9.99, 'dimension24': 18.0, 'category': 'Telefon', 'dimension9': 'Cep Telefonları'}, {'name': 'CASPER VIA F20 128 GB Akıllı Telefon Beyaz', 'id': '1216984', 'price': '2999.00', 'brand': 'CASPER', 'ean': '8699247212134', 'dimension25': 'InStock', 'dimension26': 11.9, 'dimension24': 18.0, 'category': 'Telefon', 'dimension9': 'Cep Telefonları', 'dimension10': 'Android Telefonlar'}, {'name': 'VIVO Y53S 128 GB Akıllı Telefon Derin Mavi', 'id': '1217949', 'price': '4499.00', 'brand': 'VIVO', 'ean': '6935117836812', 'dimension25': 'InStock', 'dimension26': 11.9, 'dimension24': 18.0, 'category': 'Telefon', 'dimension9': 'Cep Telefonları', 'dimension10': 'Android Telefonlar'}, {'name': 'OPPO A74 128 GB Akıllı Telefon Gece Mavisi', 'id': '1215862', 'price': '4499.00', 'brand': 'OPPO', 'ean': '8683040000227', 'dimension25': 'InStock', 'dimension26': 11.9, 'dimension24': 18.0, 'category': 'Telefon', 'dimension9': 'Cep Telefonları', 'dimension10': 'Android Telefonlar'}, {'name': 'XIAOMI Redmi 9T 128 GB Akıllı Telefon Gri', 'id': '1216310', 'price': '3399.00', 'brand': 'XIAOMI', 'ean': '6934177746086', 'dimension25': 'InStock', 'dimension26': 11.9, 'dimension24': 18.0, 'category': 'Telefon', 'dimension9': 'Cep Telefonları', 'dimension10': 'Android Telefonlar'}, {'name': 'VIVO Y53S 128 GB Akıllı Telefon Gökkuşağı', 'id': '1218011', 'price': '4499.00', 'brand': 'VIVO', 'ean': '6935117836829', 'dimension25': 'InStock', 'dimension26': 11.9, 'dimension24': 18.0, 'category': 'Telefon', 'dimension9': 'Cep Telefonları', 'dimension10': 'Android Telefonlar'}, {'name': 'OPPO A55 64GB Akıllı Telefon Yıldızlı Siyah', 'id': '1218661', 'price': '3499.00', 'brand': 'OPPO', 'ean': '8683040000418', 'dimension25': 'InStock', 'dimension26': 11.9, 'dimension24': 18.0, 'category': 'Telefon', 'dimension9': 'Cep Telefonları', 'dimension10': 'Android Telefonlar', 'dimension11': 'Oppo Telefon'}, {'name': 'OPPO A55 64GB Akıllı Telefon Gökkuşağı Mavisi', 'id': '1218660', 'price': '3499.00', 'brand': 'OPPO', 'ean': '8683040000425', 'dimension25': 'InStock', 'dimension26': 11.9, 'dimension24': 18.0, 'category': 'Telefon', 'dimension9': 'Cep Telefonları', 'dimension10': 'Android Telefonlar', 'dimension11': 'Oppo Telefon'}, {'name': 'TCL 20 E 32 GB Akıllı Telefon Mavi', 'id': '1217712', 'price': '2399.00', 'brand': 'TCL', 'ean': '4894461894812', 'dimension25': 'InStock', 'dimension26': 11.9, 'dimension24': 18.0, 'category': 'Telefon', 'dimension9': 'Cep Telefonları', 'dimension10': 'Android Telefonlar'}, {'name': 'OPPO A74 128 GB Akıllı Telefon Prizma Siyahı', 'id': '1215856', 'price': '4499.00', 'brand': 'OPPO', 'ean': '8683040000210', 'dimension25': 'InStock', 'dimension26': 11.9, 'dimension24': 18.0, 'category': 'Telefon', 'dimension9': 'Cep Telefonları', 'dimension10': 'Android Telefonlar'}, {'name': 'APPLE iPhone 11 128GB Akıllı Telefon Mor', 'id': '1212837', 'price': '10849.00', 'brand': 'APPLE', 'ean': '0194252100431', 'dimension25': 'InStock', 'dimension26': 9.99, 'dimension24': 18.0, 'category': 'Telefon', 'dimension9': 'Cep Telefonları'}, {'name': 'XIAOMI Redmi Note 10 S 128 GB Akıllı Telefon Beyaz', 'id': '1217380', 'price': '4999.00', 'brand': 'XIAOMI', 'ean': '6934177748431', 'dimension25': 'InStock', 'dimension26': 11.9, 'dimension24': 18.0, 'category': 'Telefon', 'dimension9': 'Cep Telefonları', 'dimension10': 'Android Telefonlar'}, {'name': 'CASPER VIA E4 32 GB Akıllı Telefon Siyah', 'id': '1216978', 'price': '2299.00', 'brand': 'CASPER', 'ean': '8699247209356', 'dimension25': 'InStock', 'dimension26': 11.9, 'dimension24': 18.0, 'category': 'Telefon', 'dimension9': 'Cep Telefonları', 'dimension10': 'Android Telefonlar'}, {'name': 'APPLE iPhone 13 Mini 128 GB Akıllı Telefon Starlight', 'id': '1217590', 'price': '14799.00', 'brand': 'APPLE', 'ean': '0194252689950', 'dimension25': 'InStock', 'dimension26': 11.9, 'dimension24': 18.0, 'category': 'Telefon', 'dimension9': 'Cep Telefonları'}, {'name': 'APPLE iPhone 13 Mini 256 GB Akıllı Telefon Starlight', 'id': '1217595', 'price': '16199.00', 'brand': 'APPLE', 'ean': '0194252691304', 'dimension25': 'InStock', 'dimension26': 11.9, 'dimension24': 18.0, 'category': 'Telefon', 'dimension9': 'Cep Telefonları'}]
```

Comment: Not print output

Comment: Thank you so much. How can I scrape full pages in the category?

Comment: To get a list of dicts , check the example - Create a dataframe based on it or iterate to get your specific contents.

Comment: How can I output like this: 
name : XIAOMI Poco X3 Pro 256 GB Akıllı Telefon Bronz
id : 1218181
price : 5799.00
brand : XIAOMI
ean : 6934177738371
dimension25 : InStock
dimension26 : 11.9
dimension24 : 18.0
category : Telefon
dimension9 : Cep Telefonları
dimension10 : Android Telefonlar

Comment: You mentioned that you do not want print in your first comment - Just iterate over `data` --> 
```for item in data:
    for k,v in item.items():
        print(k, ":", v)```

Each question should focus on only one issue, this particular one is answered in my opinion. additional issues are predestined to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) ([`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module) to extract the the line and then treat it with [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) to parse the json value into a `dict`

Here is a sample snippet:

```
import re, json

test = '<script>var product1218181 = {"name":"XIAOMI Poco X3 Pro 256 GB Akıllı Telefon Bronz","id":"1218181","price":"5799.00","brand":"XIAOMI","ean":"6934177738371","dimension25":"InStock","dimension26":11.90,"dimension24":18.00,"category":"Telefon","dimension9":"Cep Telefonları","dimension10":"Android Telefonlar"};</script>'

pattern = re.compile('.*?var product.+ = (.*?);.*?')
match = pattern.match(test)
if match is not None:
    data = json.loads(match.groups()[0])
    for key, value in data.items():
        print(key, ":", value)
```

**output:**

```
name : XIAOMI Poco X3 Pro 256 GB Akıllı Telefon Bronz
id : 1218181
price : 5799.00
brand : XIAOMI
ean : 6934177738371
dimension25 : InStock
dimension26 : 11.9
dimension24 : 18.0
category : Telefon
dimension9 : Cep Telefonları
dimension10 : Android Telefonlar
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but product1218181 is veriable. So website have different id's for each products. example; var product{id}

Comment: @Sadik170 you can use `product.+` in the regex for that.  check the update please

Comment: I updated my ask.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this script to parse the JSON inside that script tag. I used `json` library along with BeautifulSoup.

First I looped through all scripts in the websites (in case there are multiple scripts and we don't have an `id` or `class` for each script) and selected the script that we need, the one that contains "name" (You can make it more accurate).

Then with simple string modifications I was able to extract the dictionary / json data.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
html = '''<script>var product1218181 = {"name":"XIAOMI Poco X3 Pro 256 GB Akıllı Telefon Bronz","id":"1218181","price":"5799.00","brand":"XIAOMI","ean":"6934177738371","dimension25":"InStock","dimension26":11.90,"dimension24":18.00,"category":"Telefon","dimension9":"Cep Telefonları","dimension10":"Android Telefonlar"};</script>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for item in soup.find_all('script'):
    if '= {"name":' in item.text:
        dictionary = item.text.split(' = ', 1)[-1][:-1]
        jsonResponse = json.loads(dictionary)
        print(jsonResponse)
```

Comment: 'name' filter not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import requests
import re, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.mediamarkt.com.tr/tr/category/_cep-telefonlar%C4%B1-504171.html"

page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

results = soup.find(id="category").find("script").text

data = json.loads(re.findall("(?:{).*(?:})", results)[0])

print(data)
```