# How to extract data from <script> using Beautiful Soup / not using Selenium?

Tags: python, html, json, beautifulsoup

I am a new coder trying to extract the following data from a script tag in HTML using BS4.

```
<script>
document.obj_data = {
    "earnings_announcements_earnings_table"   : 
             [  [ "11/22/22", "9/2022", "-$0.02", "-$0.06", 
"<div class=\"right neg negative neg_icon showinline down\">-0.04</div>", 
"<div class=\"right neg negative neg_icon showinline down\">-200.00%</div>", 
"--" ] ,  [ "8/30/22", "6/2022", "-$0.05", "-$0.04", 
"<div class=\"right pos positive pos_icon showinline up\">+0.01</div>", 
"<div class=\"right pos positive pos_icon showinline up\">+20.00%</div>", "Before Open" ]  ]
                
                ,
    "earnings_announcements_sales_table"      : 
             [  [ "11/22/22", "9/2022", "$1,096.70", "$1,091.78", 
"<div class=\"right neg negative neg_icon showinline down\">-4.92</div>",

...
```

So far I've used the following code to get this specific script:

```
x = requests.get(base_url, headers = params).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(x, 'html.parser')
data = soup.find_all('script')
txt = data[25]
```

However I can't figure out or find any other solution that will output the data into a nice format like json. I can get this information using Selenium, but I would like to avoid as it is a heavy and slow process. Please help, thank you!

**EDIT:**
Others have suggested a solution that uses regex and I've tried to adjust code to fit my problem. But the output is an empty list: `[]`

```
output = [json.loads(m.group(1)) for m inre.finditer(r'document.obj_data.+ = ({.*})', x.text)]
```

Comment: well, you need JavaScript parser for that, dont you?

Comment: If you fetch the page using some method that understands javascript, then that table should appear normally.  Don't use `requests` for pages that rely on javascript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scraping JavaScript var from website using Beautiful Soup in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70644965/scraping-javascript-var-from-website-using-beautiful-soup-in-python)

Comment: @HedgeHog I've tried that solution to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

this is how i usually do it:

```
import json
...

txt_json= json.loads(txt.string)
print(json.dumps(txt_json, indent=4))
...
```

Comment: I get the following ```JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)```

Comment: did you replace soup.find_all with soup.find ? with find_all you would have to iterate over your results

Comment: There's multiple scripts in the soup, so I found the specific script I want to extract with txt.

Comment: i see. ive edited my  code. you can add this beneath your txt = data[25]

Comment: I'm still receiving the same error.

Comment: your txt probably is looking strange. check how exactly your txt variable looks like and if its formatted correcty

Comment: You need to use `.get_text()` to actually extract text from the BeautifulSoup object?